# Mathematica: Defining a function as the derivative or integral of a piecewise defined function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to evaluate a function that I have defined piecewise. I need to integrate it with respect to one variable and then take the derivative with respect to another (variables are independent). However, something in the way I am defining the functions is causing mathematica to throw errors or infinitely evaluate. I believe that the derivative function does not like the format of the output of the integrate function, and vice versa when I tired reversing the order of the steps. The integrand is not analytical by hand, so I need to pipe the output of one into the other. Can anyone tell me what is going wrong?

```
\[Theta] = 30 Degree; 
d = 50.8*10^-3 ;
reo = (150/2)*10^-3; 
rei = ((reo/Tan[\[Theta]]) - 
    d) Tan[\[Theta]] 

B = 24.4*10^-3; 
\[CapitalGamma] = 10*10^-3; 
l = .2*10^-3; 
\[CurlyPhi] = 20 Degree;

Pe = 101325; 
Ps = 1.1* Pe ;

\[Gamma] = (\[CurlyPhi]*Sin[\[Theta]])/(B*\[CapitalGamma]^3);
Pd[h_] := 
 Sqrt[((Ps^2 + Pe^2*\[Gamma]*h^3*(l + h) + 
      Log[rei/reo])/(1 + \[Gamma]*h^3*(l + h) + Log[rei/reo]))]

rd = Sqrt[reo*rei]
P [r_, h_] := 
  Piecewise[{{Sqrt[
      Pd[h]^2 + .5*(Pe^2 - Pd[h]^2)*Log[rei/reo]*Log[rd/r]], 
     r > rd}, {Sqrt[
      Pd[h]^2 + .5*(Pe^2 - Pd[h]^2)*Log[rei/reo]*Log[r/rd]], r < rd}}];
W[h_] := Integrate[2*Pi*r*P[r, h]/9.8, {r, rei, reo}]
S[h_] := D[W[h], h]

Plot[{P[r, 10*10^-6], P[r, 8*10^-6], P[r, 6*10^-6], P[r, 4*10^-6], 
  P[r, 2*10^-6], P[r, 1*10^-6]}, {r, rei, reo}]
Plot[W[h], {h, 1*10^-6, 10*10^-6}]
Plot[S[h], {h, 1*10^-6, 10*10^-6}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to do a very complicated calculation a very large number of times in that integral and then a very very large number of times to make that plot. On my system, it takes 10s just to get one point. So you need to make it a lot faster. I recommend compiling `P` like so:

```
P = Compile[{{r, _Real}, {h, _Real}}, 
  Module[{Pdh = Sqrt[(
     Ps^2 + Pe^2 \[Gamma] h^3 (l + h) + Log[rei/reo])/(
     1 + \[Gamma] h^3 (l + h) + 
      Log[rei/reo])]}, \[Sqrt](Pdh^2 + .5 (Pe^2 - Pdh^2) Log[rei/
        reo] Log[Min[rd, r]/Max[rd, r]])]]
```

That will make things a lot faster, but now we need to make sure we're always using numerical expressions, not symbolic ones. That means the integral needs to become

```
W[h_] := NIntegrate[(2 \[Pi] r P[r, h])/9.8, {r, rei, reo}]
```

and the derivative needs to become

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]
S[h_] := ND[W[hh], hh, h]
```

This makes things about 100 times faster, and the plots come out. You may still see some warning messages, but they can be ignored. Throw a `Quiet` around the definitions of `W` and `S` if it bothers you.

Comment: Not really relevant. The issue is that trying to take a derivative of P either before or after the integral seems to be causing issues since the h dependance is inside of Pd, rather than directly in P.

Comment: Trivial counterexample: `Pd[h_]:=Sin[h^2];P[r_,h_]:=r^2+8 Pd[h];W[h_]:=Integrate[\[Pi] P[r,h],{r,0,1}];S[h_]:=(D[W[hh],hh]/.hh->h);Plot[S[h],{h,0,2 \[Pi]}]`. Did you try the given solution? It works for me; if it does not work for you, can you say why it failed?

Comment: S[h_]:=(D[W[hh],hh]/.hh->h) As soon as I did this instead of S[h_]:=D[W[h],h], it started working. I am not sure what this means, though, or why the first version is wrong.

Comment: Ah, I kind of glossed over that. When you use `S` inside of a `Plot`, the `h` is the dependent variable of the plot; that is, it's a real number. You can't take a derivative with respect to a real number. So instead, you use a dummy variable `hh` and substitute `h` in after the derivative.

Comment: I take that back I am still getting errors it is just producing a graph now instead of nothing.           

NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand 0.641141 r (\[Piecewise] Sqrt[Power[<<2>>] Plus[<<2>>]-0.420686 Plus[<<2>>] Log[<<1>>]] r>0.0491988
Sqrt[Power[<<2>>] Plus[<<2>>]-0.420686 Plus[<<2>>] Log[<<1>>]] r<0.0491988
0 True
) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0.0323037,0.07493}}. >>

Comment: I mentioned that might happen; it's nothing to worry about. Before the `Plot` gets down to the business of making the plot, it tries to do a bit of simplification of the expression to see if it can make it go faster. Those simplifications make certain assumptions about the symbolic nature of the expression that we're violating. Eventually after throwing those warnings, `Plot` will give up and do it the slow way.